# General Debug Efficiency

Tags: debugging, performance

I wanted to know which one of these would be more time-efficient when implementing new features/whatever in a library:

- Write it little by little, perfecting each stage
- Write the entire feature, and debug the whole thing at once.

I just wanted some thoughts on this. Thanks :)

Comment: In my experience,  #1 is how you should do it, and #2 is how you end up doing it. #1 will make you more productive on the long run if you stick to it and use it in conjunction with test-driven development. #2 will make you more productive in the short term, but then all hell breaks loose when you start fixing bugs in class A and it breaks class B, C, and D. That being said, I think this question is more suited for [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generally advised to do incremental coding ( your first option ) so that your are sure that at least some part of your feature is working before you move on.
Debugging everything at once will be a big headache as you will not know which part of the code the error is in. 
In the long run , the first way will definitely be faster than the second one.

Comment: Thanks! Without factoring error location, they evened out in my head.